# Azure AD: can not LOG IN after LOG OUT MVC5.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have web application that should support Azure AD.
I already have successful log in with redirect Home/Index
Also successful log out with redirect to Home/Index.
But when i am trying to log in after log out error occurs "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again"

in azure itself shown that all loggings are successful. Moreover, if clear browser  cash and reload - it redirects to necessary logged user. Any ideas how to resolve it?

//Startup

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = "openid profile", // Include any other required scopes
                
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false // Set to true if you want to validate the issuer
                },
                MetadataAddress = metadataAddress, 
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()             
            });
        }
```

Logout Method in user controller

```
 public void Logout()
        {

            // Clear session data on logout
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            HttpContext.Session.Abandon(); // Optional, but recommended

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                //new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);         
        }
```

Home/Index

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var name = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            var x = HttpContext.Session["UserID"];
            // If the user is authenticated, redirect to the appropriate view based on user type
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
               // var name = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                HttpContext.Session["UserID"] = name;
                if (User.IsInRole("some role"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                }
            }
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the user is not authenticated, initiate the Azure AD authentication flow
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
                );

            }


            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

I tried to clear cookies after logout but it didn't helped.

[image]

Also during debugging i noticed that it just looped in Index, cause User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false ( but it should be true after entering credentials)

Comment: Could you please share your App Registrations => Authentication => Redirect URI Screen Shot.

Comment: What is the framework of your application?

Comment: @Harshitha ASP.MVC5.

Comment: @Harshitha updated decription

Comment: Change the redirect uri as `https://localhost:57354/signin-oidc` and check once.

Comment: @Harshitha isn't singin-oidc supportde by .net core only?

Comment: Yes,it is supported by .NET Core only.

Comment: The authentication cookie is not getting cleared.Add this line of code `new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri }` after `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,` in Logout() method.

Comment: @Harshitha didn't helped. i also think that problem in some cashing but idk how to fix it.  in code user is logged out successfully and redirected to index. but second log in is failed

Comment: Will try from my end and let you know.

Comment: Iam able to login for the second time by changing the `return new EmptyResult();`  to `return View();`.Once check from your end.

Comment: Remove the else condition for User.IsRole and add as, `if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                }`

Comment: @Harshitha changing return new EmptyResult(); to return View(); didn't help. 
are those configs from web config fine?

<add key="ida:ClientId" value="appid" />
  <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" />
  <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:57354/Home/Index" />
  <add key="ida:MetadataAddress" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
  <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:57354/Home/Index" />

Comment: Yes..the configurations are from the web.configfile.

Comment: What is the User.IsRole you are getting?

Comment: Have you changed the user.isrole else part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved it by myself: the last version of Microsoft.Owin (4.2.2) is bugged. I rolled bacl to version 4.1.0 and everything started to work. It took 5 days for me to figured out.